# Symfony Route. Can't set annotations

Tags: symfony, symfony-routing

I can't understand, if i create crud controller with

bin/console make:crud all routes work from controller

like

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="product_index", methods="GET")
 */

public function index(ProductRepository $productRepository): Response

{
    return $this->render('product/index.html.twig', ['products' => $productRepository->findAll()]);
}
```

.

If i create controller with bin/console make:controller

and define controller with annotation by myself they don't work

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use App\Entity\Product;
use App\Repository\ProductRepository;

use JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

class FirstApiController extends AbstractController
{
  /**
   *
   * @Route("/first_api", name="first_api")
   */
  public function index(ProductRepository $productRepository)
  {
      $data = $productRepository->findAll();
      $serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
#      $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json');

      $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('details')));


      $response = JsonResponse::fromJsonString($jsonContent);
      return $response;

  }

    /*
     * @Route("/first_api/send", name="send")
     *
     */
    public function send()
    {
        $a = "text";
        return $a;
    }

}
```

Why that route doesn't work

```
@Route("/first_api/send", name="send") ?
```

In routes.yaml i wrote nothing, just empty file.

Comment: I think your problem is resolved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used wrong syntax !I used

```
/*  <-- the error is here
 * @Route("/first_api/send", name="send")
 *
 */
```

I need to use

```
/**  <-- i nee two "*"
 * @Route("/first_api/send", name="send")
 *
 */
public
```